# How to fill a form with CasperJS or PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, forms, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to fill a form by using *id, cssSelector, className, name, XPath etc..*. Is it possible by using CasperJS or PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are wanting to know is if it can be done. Yes it is doable. In both CasperJS and PhantomJS.  For that matter it can be done in vanilla Javascript.

```
this.fillSelectors('form#contact', {
    'input[name = name ]' : 'John Doe',
    'input[name = email ]' : 'xyz@email.com',
    'input[name = phone ]' : '123456789'
});
```

CasperJS provides four functions to fill by *name, CSS3 selector, label or XPath expression*.

Comment: Hello sir, I don't understand.. I just wanted to know.. Suppose i want to login into Facebook.. Where i could see `input` as text box and `submit` button etc. Into Selenium we could enter it by using `findElement(By.id etc)`.. But how to parse element by using `phantomJS`. Can it be done by using `CasperJS`? Please let me know sir :)

Comment: Please have a look at the docs here. [link]http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors [/link]There is all the info you need to answer your question. No?

Comment: Thank you sir.. :) One thing please help me sir, I've successfully downloaded `casperjs` ..I've set my path of `Phantomjs` and `casperjs` .. now i'm running simple program of casper js.. It says `Couldn't find nor compute phantom.casperPath, exiting.

  C:\casperjs\batchbin\..\bin\bootstrap.js:241 in loadCasper` Please help me sir ... Request to you Please

Comment: Which version numbers of PhantomJS and CasperJS are you using?

Comment: Sir, I'm using the latest version of `phantomJS 2.0` and `casperjs 1.0.4` ..When i run my program `$phantomjs casperjs mySimple.js` ..

Comment: It gives me output as `Can't open casperjs`

Comment: Not sure but try putting the following in the bootstrap.js  `var system = require('system');
 var argsdeprecated = system.args;
 argsdeprecated.shift();
 phantom.args = argsdeprecated;`

Comment: Not working :( ..Is there any other way for scraping?

Comment: I know in some of the latest versions of PhantomJS there have be compatibility problems with Casper because some arguments have been depreciated. Maybe try using a version PhantomJS before 2.0

Comment: Sir, Do you know any other good scraper ? which tends to work with `phantomjs`? If yes, Please let me know sir?

Comment: Node.js is often used with Phantom.  But I am not all that familiar with using it that way. Sorry.  Maybe this will help http://code4node.com/snippet/web-scraping-with-node-and-phantomjs